# Play 2 framework two legged OAuth

Tags: oauth, playframework-2.0

I want to do application(Play 2) to application(Spring) Private API call that is secured by OAuth 1.X. How can I do that in Play 2 framework? Following [this](http://playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaOAuth) example I was able to invoke the service in 3 legged way. What changes I should make to switch to 2 legged way?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found [Steven Phung's gist on github](https://gist.github.com/stphung/1908571):

```
def doRequest(key: String, secret: String) {
  val ck = ConsumerKey(key, secret)
  val calc = OAuthCalculator(ck, RequestToken("", ""))
  calc.setSendEmptyTokens(true)
  WS.url(endpoint).sign(calc).get.map(response => {
    println(response.json)
  })
}
```

This code snippet assumes that you have empty request token key and secret. If you have a specific token key and secret that you need to provide to calculate the OAuth signature, then you need to provide them as arguments to the constructor of RequestToken.

The classes you need to import can be found in `play.api.libs.oauth._`.

Comment: The method `setSendEmptyTokens()` doesn't seem to exist anymore in later versions of Play, but it works very well without it as well.